# How to save non ASCII Characters in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, unidecoder

This question is repeated, but I can not find answer to problem in my context. I am trying to save `Aéropostale` as string in mongo DB:

```
name='Aéropostale'
obj=Mongo_Object()
obj.name=name
obj.save()
```

When I save the object, I get following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

How to proceed to save the string in original format and retrieve in same format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using Python 2.7, you need to do a few things:

1. [Specify the file encoding](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), by adding a string similar to this to the top of your file:

   ```
   #coding: utf8
   ```
2. Use a [unicode string](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), as your string is not ASCII, and specify the encoding. I am using utf8 here which includes `é`:

   ```
   name = unicode('Aéropostale', 'utf8')
   ```